# CodeIgniter and JConfirmAction

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I'm currently using jConfirmAction for confirming my delete options...however because I use CodeIgniter the page is being refreshed rather than being submitted...any ideas on how I can fix this? Thanks

This is the page where it is going to but instead of refreshing I need it to submit...

```
$('.yes').bind('click', function(){
   window.location = "http://localhost:8888/website/admin/entries";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just redirecting via javascript.  To submit a form do this..

```
$('.yes').bind('click', function(){
   $('#form-id').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use Ajax:

```
$.post('<?php echo site_url('website/admin/entries');?>', {'field', 'value'}, function(data)) {
    // a return response
}
```

If you don't need anything to refresh